# javax.xml.crypto.dsig.TransformException: Couldn't find Transform for: http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#

Tags: java, authentication, aem

We send a SAML request to ADFS and in response we get proper SAML response as well but after that I get the error as below
javax.xml.crypto.dsig.TransformException: Couldn't find Transform for: http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#

For more details please check the  [link](https://developer.jboss.org/message/739382#739382) but its not answered there too.

Could anyone please help us to understand the problem and hepl us to resolve the same.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: In AEM, as long as the configuration of the auth handler is correct, the only other reason for any such error is incorrect SAML from IDP. Are you positive that SAML is in valid format and your config is also correct ?

Comment: Hi Abhishek
Thanks for response ! yes the SAML response and config both are correct. And this issue I resolved just by redeployment to server but still I do not know the root cause.